# AndroidX library messed up with CheckBoxes in my app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-checkbox, androidx

I used v7 support library and I switched to AndroidX today. My CheckBox behaviour changed.

I'm using alot of checkboxes in this app but I will give you example here:

I have two checkboxes: If user checked CheckBox1, CheckBox2 should uncheck. If user checked CheckBox2, Chechbox1 should uncheck.

Code:

```
//global max min
    globalMaxCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
        if (isChecked){
            globalMinCheckBox.isChecked = false
        }
    }

    globalMinCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
        if (isChecked){
            globalMaxCheckBox.isChecked = false
        } 
    }
```

After AndroidX update: If user checks CheckBox1 it will stay checked (magenta color CheckBox). But if user checks CheckBox2, CheckBox1 will change color from magenta to gray and it stays checked together with CheckBox2(checked and has magenta color).

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup

Comment: @martin1337 do you find a solution for this issue?

Comment: Nope, Ive used RadioGroup